# Why doesn't FIRST_COMPLETED in python futures return earlier?

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait, as_completed, FIRST_COMPLETED
from time import sleep
from random import randint


def return_after_5_secs(num):
    sleep(randint(1, 5))
    return "Return of {}".format(num)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(5)
    futures = []
    for x in range(5):
        futures.append(pool.submit(return_after_5_secs, x))

    done, not_done = wait(futures, return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
    print(f"done: {done}")
    print(f"not_done: {not_done}")
    for f in done:
        print(f.result())
```

We can control the behavior of the wait function by defining when it should return. We can pass one of these values to the return_when param of the function: FIRST_COMPLETED, FIRST_EXCEPTION and ALL_COMPLETED. By default, it’s set to ALL_COMPLETED, so the wait function returns only when all futures complete. But using that parameter, we can choose to return when the first future completes or first exception encounters.

But why are my results this:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.9 /Users/JeffreyWan/python-tutorial/futures/wait.py
done: {<Future at 0x10f1efa90 state=finished returned str>, <Future at 0x10f1efdc0 state=finished returned str>}
not_done: {<Future at 0x10f227130 state=running>, <Future at 0x10f227460 state=running>, <Future at 0x10f2277f0 state=running>}
Return of 0
Return of 1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It seems like 2 futures are in the done section. Why would there be ... more than 1?